# How can I make my image appear in a random position?

Tags: java, random, collision

I have a chicken image that only moves whenever I press my arrow keys, the image always appear at the lower left corner when I start to run the program. My problem is that how can I make the image appear at the top or anywhere on the screen(except on the lower left) and the image still moves when I press the arrow keys . I'm not really sure but I think this problem is coming from my translate(). Is there something wrong with my calculation? Thanks for sharing your ideas...

Here's the code...

```
public class Chicken extends Sprite implements ImageObserver
{
private java.awt.Image fishImage;
private final Board board;
private double x;
private double y;
private final double chickenHeight = 1.6;
private final double chickenWidth = 1.8;  
private double speed;
private boolean visible;
private double angle;
private double dx_m;
private double dy_m;
private boolean collision = false;

public Chicken(Board board, String name, double x, double y, double speed)
{
    super(name);

    this.board = board;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.speed = convertToMeterPerSecond(speed);
    visible = true;

    URL iU = this.getClass().getResource("chicken.jpg");
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(iU);
    chickenImage = icon.getImage();
}

public Image getImage()
{
    return chickenImage;
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
{

    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
    {
        dx_m = -0.5;
    }
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
    {
        dx_m = 0.5;
    }
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
    {
        dy_m = 0.5;
    }
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
    {
        dy_m = -0.5;
    }
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
{
    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
    {
        dx_m = 0;
    }
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
    {
        dx_m = 0;
    }
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
    {
        dy_m = 0;
    }
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
    {
        dy_m = 0;
    }
}

@Override
public void move(long dt)
{

     double right_wall = board.x1_world;
     double up_wall = board.y1_world;
     double down_wall = 0.0;
     double left_wall = 0.0;

    x += dx_m;
    y += dy_m;

    if (x >= right_wall)
    {
        x = right_wall;          
    }
    if (y > up_wall)
    {
        y = up_wall;
    }
    if (x <= left_wall)
    {
        x = left_wall;
    }
    if (y < down_wall)
    {
        y = down_wall;
    }
}

@Override
public void render(Graphics2D g2d)
{
    AffineTransform t = g2d.getTransform();
    final double foot_position_y = chickenHeight;
    final double foot_position_x = chickenWidth / 2;

    double xx = board.convertToPixelX(x - foot_position_x); 
    double yy = board.convertToPixelY(y + foot_position_y);
    g2d.translate(xx, yy);
//        ratio for the actual size of the Image
    double x_expected_pixels = chickenHeight * board.meter;
    double y_expected_pixels = chickenWidth * board.meter;

    double w = ((ToolkitImage) chickenImage).getWidth();
    double h = ((ToolkitImage) chickenImage).getHeight();

    double x_s = x_expected_pixels / w;
    double y_s = y_expected_pixels / h;
    g2d.scale(x_s, y_s);
    g2d.drawImage(getImage(), (int) x, (int) y, this); 
    g2d.setTransform(t);
}

@Override
public void moveAt(double distance_x, double distance_y)
{
    this.x = (int) distance_x;
    this.y = (int) distance_y;
}

public void setAngle(double angle)
{
    this.angle = angle;
}

@Override
public RectangleX getBounds()
{
    return new RectangleX(x, y, chickenWidth, chickenHeight);
}

@Override
public double getWidth()
{
    return WIDTH;
}

@Override
public double getHeight()
{
    return HEIGHT;
}

@Override
public boolean imageUpdate(Image img, int infoflags, int x, int y, int width, int height)
{
    return true;
}

}
```

this is my chicken class

```
public double meter;
int y1_pixel;

y1_pixel = getHeight(); 

public int convertToPixelX(double distance)
{
    return (int) (distance * meter);
}

public int convertToPixelY(double y_world)
{
    return (int) (y1_pixel - (y_world * meter));
}
```

this is coming from my board class.

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980051/how-to-make-a-random-position-whenever-i-start-running-the-program/7980205#7980205) might be your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your render method is using the x and y coordinates of the class to determine where to draw the Chicken each time.  A simple solution to your problem is to use random values for x and y when you create a Chicken instance.

An alternate solution would be to create another constructor that do not take values for x or y and instead sets them to be default values anywhere between 0 and board.x1_world or board.y1_world, depending on the variable.

```
public Chicken(Board board, String name, double speed)
{
    this( board, name,
          (int)( Math.random() * ( board.x1_world - chickenWidth ) ),
          (int)( Math.random() * ( board.y1_world - chickenHeight ) ),
          speed );
}
```